# Collections in PHP

Tags: c#, php, inheritance, collections

I want to replicate a class in C# into a PHP class. The name of my C# class is, Award which is a child class of the BaseDocument class. The source code of my files is:

*BaseDocument.cs*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for BaseDocument
/// </summary>

    public class BaseDocument
    {
        public BaseDocument()
        {
            //
            // TODO: Add constructor logic here
            //
        }
    }
```

*Award.cs*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for Award
/// </summary>
public class Award : BaseDocument
{
    private List<string> _testimonials;

    public Award()
        : base()
    {
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //
    }
}
```

The problem here is that Award is a child of BaseDocument and contains a field, _testimonials which is a collection of the List type. I want to replicate all of this in PHP. Can anyone please tell me how can I create this inheritance hierarchy and a collection in PHP of similar type?

Replies at the earliest will be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Isn't List just an usual Array?

Comment: Maybe just `class Award extends BaseDocument { private $_testimonials = array(); }`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, if you need `List` like in `C#`,  try reading about [Iterator interface](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php) and make like this (simple example):

```
class List  implements Iterator {
   private $position = 0;
   private $array = array();  

public function __construct(array $list) { // array of string or objects or assoc.array
    $this->array = $list;
    $this->position = 0;
}

public add($item){
     $this->array[] = $item;   
} 

public delete($position){
     unset($this->array[$position]);
}


function rewind() {
    $this->position = 0;
}

function current() {
    return $this->array[$this->position];
}

function key() {
    return $this->position;
}

function next() {
     ++$this->position;
}   


}
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be something like this in PHP.

Try reading about [classes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) in PHP before asking people to code stuff for you.

Also

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

```
class BaseDocument
{
    public function __construct()
    {
    }
}

class Award extends BaseDocument
{
    private $_testimonials = array();

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for replying. I will read the OOPs guidelines on PHP and then start working on designing my classes.

Answer (score 1):

Parent class

```
   Class BaseDocument{
      public function __construct(){
         //base class constructor logic
      }
    }
```

Child class

```
class Award extends BaseDocument{
   protected $_testimonials = array();
   public function __construct(){
     parent::__construct()// if you want to call parent class constructor
     //child class constructor logic
      $this->_testimonials[] = "Hello World";//Assigning string to array
   }
}
```